# How can change map api v1 key which is already on google play store?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have one application in which i was use google map v1.Before few day ago suddenly map not shown in it.show need to update that code .but currently google map api v2 is use and i can not recreate v1 key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you want to switch over to Google map v2. In map v1 you have used Overlays,it will not support in Google map v2.So not only key you want to do rework for your project by replacing it and moreover google map v1 keys were not maintained by Google, so only map looks blank. So the only solution is, you want to switch your code to Google map v2.

Answer (score 0):

Your v1 key is in the code.

If you don't have release signing key (usually hidden in a file named `something.keystore`), you are out of luck and cannot update the application even with GM Android API v2.